# "No table found" Android SQLite issue

Tags: java, android, sqlite, android-emulator

i am having an issue and racking my brain trying to figure out why it wont work.
here is the code

```
import java.io.*;
import android.content.Context;
import android.database.SQLException;
import android.database.sqlite.*;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;


public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{
    //The Android's default system path of your application database.
    private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/teamawesome.spots.namespac/databases/";

    private static String DB_NAME = "Final.db3";

    //private static String DB_TABLE = "Restaurant";

    public SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;

private final Context myContext;

/****
 * Constructor
 *
 * Takes and keeps a reference of the passed context in order to access to the           application assets and resources.
 * @param context
 ***/
public DataBaseHelper(Context context)
{
    super(context, DB_NAME, null, 1);
    this.myContext = context;
}   


 /**
 * Creates a empty database on the system and rewrites it with your own database.
 * */
public void createDataBase() throws IOException{

    boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();

    if(dbExist)
    {
        //do nothing - database already exist
    }
    else
    {
    //By calling this method and empty database will be created into the default      system path
        //of your application so we are gonna be able to overwrite that database with our database.
        this.getReadableDatabase();
        try
        {
            copyDataBase();
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            throw new Error("Error copying database");
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Check if the database already exist to avoid re-copying the file each time you open the application.
 * @return true if it exists, false if it doesn't
 */
private boolean checkDataBase()
{
    SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
    try
    {
        String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e)
    {
        //database does't exist yet.
    }
    if(checkDB != null)
    {
        checkDB.close();
    }
    return checkDB != null ? true : false;
}

/**
 * Copies your database from your local assets-folder to the just created empty database in the
 * system folder, from where it can be accessed and handled.
 * This is done by transfering bytestream.
 * */
private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
{
    //Open your local db as the input stream
    InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DB_NAME);

    // Path to the just created empty db
    String outFileName = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;

    //Open the empty db as the output stream
    OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);

    //transfer bytes from the inputfile to the outputfile
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int length;
    while ((length = myInput.read(buffer))>0)
    {
        myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    //Close the streams
    myOutput.flush();
    myOutput.close();
    myInput.close();
}

public void openDataBase() throws SQLException
{
    //Open the database
    String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
    myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
}

@Override
public synchronized void close()
{
        if(myDataBase != null)
            myDataBase.close();
        super.close();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
{

}

public String Alphabetical()
{
    Cursor c = null;
    c = (Cursor)myDataBase.query(DB_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    String sql = "SELECT * FROM Restaurant";
    c = myDataBase.rawQuery(sql, null);
    return c;
}
```

Any and all help is appreciated.

thank you

Comment: are you able to open this db in sqlite browser or via console and see what output for .schema

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to do in copyDataBase but I recommend you to use a more standardize way to interact with SQL databases: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#db

Comment: It would help if you gave at least a one-sentence explanation of what your code is supposed to do, and then another (roughly) one-sentence of what problem you are encountering.
Showing us the code is great, but it saves us a lot of time to have a quick explanation as well.

Comment: @chris  When you say 'it wont work', you should specify which method failed in your code.

Answer (score 2):

In you `onCreate` method you should do all the stuff for creating tables in your new database, like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
{
    db.execSql("create table if not exists Restaraunt (...)");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to implement a database with almost no problems... I followed this example:  [Database Management...](http://www.barebonescoder.com/2010/05/android-development-database-management/)  This was the best example for getting started.  After that there are several more advanced examples (found with google) that helped with more advanced topics like error trapping and updating.

Answer (score 0):

You should use `SQLiteDatabase.NO_LOCALIZED_COLLATORS` flag also in the `openDatabase` call if you are copying the database. This will cause LOCALIZED collator not to be created.

You must be missing android-metadata table which is created with locale when not using the specified flag. And then, you are copying a DB over it which doesn't have it.